# Empty rows in report when using count function

Tags: eclipse, report, reporting, birt

I am using BIRT reporting with my mongodb datasource. I am trying to COUNT some events. COUNT function gives the correct value but there is big empty space at the end of the page depending upon the count value. If the count value is big then the rest of the page is empty and on the next page same record is coming e.g. :
In this Image the rest of the page is empty and same record is coming on the next pages also. It looks like empty spaces are being printed.

[image]

This is how my report looks like :

[image]

The COUNT function:

[image]

I have tried using SUM also but I get this error when I use SUM function instead of COUNT :

```
    org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Can not convert the value of True to Double type.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.DataItemExecutor.execute(DataItemExecutor.java:101)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.execute(HTMLAbstractLM.java:468)
```

Please help, thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue to this problem. If we select "Hide Detail" Option from the group then this problem go away.

[image]